Redis AOF rewrite cause CPU spikes
We have a redis K8s pod where
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb

The base file is around 2GB, and when BGREWRITEAOF starts CPU spikes for around 3 minutes.
Any idea what configuration can prevent this situation from happening?
Reducing the percentage might cause more frequent but shorter spikes?
